# Check if Profile is linked to Linked identity providers?

Tags: keycloak, pac4j

I have a running Keycloak and using Pac4j.
Some accounts have an access directly to Keycloak (password and username stored there in the database).
But I have enabled also login via Social Login (e.g. Google). Those accounts have an entry in Keycloak, but mapped to a Social Login.

I would like to implement via Keycloak API a "Password Reset", but this make only sense for those accounts, which stored with password directly in Keycloak database (= no Social Login).

How can I check if a Account (Profile) is mapped to a Social Login via Pac4j?
I thought maybe I can get this information with `KeycloakOidcProfile` but I haven´t found any property.

Here this information from Keycloak
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

pac4j only maps what exists in Keycloak so it really depends on what you have in Keycloak and what you can push to pac4j.

Comment: Not sure what you exactly mean... In Keycloak (Tab: Identity provider links) I have this information... I have updated my question with a picture...

Comment: pac4j data the user profile data from the IDToken and the data returned in the UserInfo endpoint so you must configure Keycloack to send all the wanted data on the UserInfo endpoint first. Check the pac4j logs on the `OidcProfileCreator`

Comment: so you want to say I need a custom attribute in Keycloak, like "social_login" to store it?

Comment: The information is available already in Keycloak without any configuration, but it´s not part of `OidcProfileCreator` .... Is pac4j using the REST API from Keycloak? Like here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/21.0.1/rest-api/index.html

Comment: pac4j uses the OIDC UserInfo endpoint to the user data.